# Will my recursive Async Function run on the UI Thread?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a question on Task.Run implementation, I’ve read other threads and just needed clarification for my use case.

Here is a synopsis of my code:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public async Task<object> Start(string arg1, string arg2)
    {    
        object result;
        If (someCondition)
            result = await OtherClass.Task(arg1, arg2); // not worried about this
        else
            result = await Run(arg1, arg2); // here is my concern
        // Cleanup
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<object> Run(arg1, arg2)
    {
        // validate args (synchronous code block)
        resultsBuilder = new();
        await Dig(MyDir);
        result = resultsBuilder.GetResults();
        // cleanup logic
        return result;
    }

    private async Task Dig(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        ForEach (file in Dir.GetFiles())
               // unsure about this spot too - which one is better for this setup?
               file.Move()
               await Task.Run(() => file.Move());

        ForEach (dir in Dir.GetDirectories())
               await Dig(dir);
    }
}
```

As can be seen, it’s effectively synchronous code, using some ForEach loops within the Dig() method. When it comes time to dig into the children directories, the Dig() function is called again, making it wait for all children to complete before exiting itself. I believe that, despite all this being awaited, its still effectively synchronous code.

This will be intially started from a UI thread, which I don't want to hang up. My understanding is that currently, each ‘await’ will return to the initial calling thread (which is likely a UI thread). Do I have that correct?

is it enough to use .ConfigureAwait(false) in the Run() method? Should It also be in the recursive Dig() method? Or should I be using Task.Run(() => Run(arg1, arg2));

OR, does it make sense to have the recursive method as synchronous with no return, then use Task.Run() on that? (And leave File.Move() as synchronous since its already running on a background thread thanks to Task.Run())
example:

```
await Task.Run(() => Dig(MyDir));

private void Dig(DirectoryInfo dir){ }
```

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] using *actual* code instead of pseudo-code. Aside from anything else, you could then test it for yourself. It's not clear to me why you're using async at all given that, as you say, you're not doing anything asynchronous... It's worth being aware that if you await a task that's already completed, it just keeps going synchronously anyway.

Comment: Am I right in the assumption that `Start` will be called from some EventHandler? Maybe a button click handler?

Comment: @JonSkeet 
I'm specifically refering to RoboMover over on this page. I'm want to just double check my logic prior to it being merged.
https://github.com/tjscience/RoboSharp/pull/181

Comment: @Fildor yea thats correct.

Comment: Ok. Two observations: First: Especially when it comes to FileSystem-Stuff, I've become a "No Recursion"-Guy. And no, I cannot give you a rational reason for it outside personal experience (=> maybe it's a me-thing). Second this (pseudo-) code does not include a way to cancel the operation (gracefully). I've seen and worked with Filesystems where such a call could run for hours ...

Comment: @RFBomb a top-level `Task.Run` that use` Directory.EnumerateFile` with a recursion flag would be a lot simpler than this. There's no need for recursion. Without a `File.MoveAsync` method there's no actual asynchronous code. If you want to perform multiple moves concurrently you could use Parallel.ForEachAsync with a limited DOP on the file sequence. This *could* offer some limited benefits.

Comment: @Fildor the actual code has methods to cancel it and break out if an exception occurs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the tip on enumerate recursive. Due to how the logging it occurring through, this procduces the desired results.

Comment: *"I believe that, despite all this being awaited, its still effectively synchronous code."* -- I think that the word "sequential" conveys the correct meaning here, instead of "synchronous".

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that, despite all this being awaited, its still effectively synchronous code.

If `Dig` uses the synchronous `Move`, then yes, it'll be completely synchronous.

> My understanding is that currently, each ‘await’ will return to the initial calling thread (which is likely a UI thread). Do I have that correct?

Close. I explain [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) how it works. When `await` is used with a task, the important parts are:

1. `await` first examines the task to determine if it is already complete. If it is, then it proceeds executing the `async` method synchronously.
2. When the task is not complete, `await` will capture the current "context", which is `SynchronizationContext.Current` or `TaskScheduler.Current`, and this context is used to resume execution after the task completes.

UI threads have a `SynchronizationContext`, so `await` will resume on the UI thread. Thread pool threads (and Console applications) do not have a `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`, so `await` will resume on *any available thread pool thread*.

> is it enough to use .ConfigureAwait(false) in the Run() method? Should It also be in the recursive Dig() method? Or should I be using Task.Run(() => Run(arg1, arg2));

`ConfigureAwait(false)` means that the context is not captured (step 2), and the `async` method resumes executing on any available thread pool thread instead. However, this only comes into play if the task isn't already completed in the first place (step 1). So, if you have already-completed tasks, then the `ConfigureAwait(false)` does *not* cause a switch to the thread pool; it just continues executing synchronously on the same thread.

> OR, does it make sense to have the recursive method as synchronous with no return, then use Task.Run() on that? (And leave File.Move() as synchronous since its already running on a background thread thanks to Task.Run())

This is exactly what I would do: a single `Task.Run` and keep the recursive method synchronous.

There's nothing *wrong* with asynchronous recursive methods, but what you're really asking about here is more about parallelism, which is complex to do correctly in this case. One aspect is that in general recursive tree structures, you usually want to limit the parallelism, so you'd end up with more of a producer/consumer or dataflow structure to the code instead of straightforward recursion. Another aspect is that this is dealing with disks, which don't tend to parallelize well (particularly non-SSDs where competing seeks means parallelism can easily be slower than serialized access).

So, to reiterate: one `Task.Run` with a straightforward recursive synchronous method is what I would recommend, if that's sufficiently efficient.